# prepend img src url

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm creating an App using html 5 phonegap and one portion of the App is drawing an rss feed in. One problem i've run into is that the feed has images in it and the url for the images is set to be draw from the server the feed is located on. For example the entire img code is:

```
<img src="/files/2012/01/brazilsal.jpg" />
```

Now since those images aren't native it won't work on the app.

So i need to prepend the src to be

```
<img src="http://management.bu.edu/files/2012/01/brazilsal.jpg" />.
```

I also need it to not affect any other image on the app.

Any ideas on how to do this in javascript or jquery?

Comment: Are you parsing the incoming RSS, or are you dropping html from the RSS directly into your page?

Answer (score 0):

You need [js-uri](http://code.google.com/p/js-uri/).

Simple example:

```
var rssUri = new URI("http://management.bu.edu/data.rss");
var imgUri = new URI("/files/2012/01/brazilsal.jpg");
var fullImgUri = imgUri.resolve(rssUri);
alert(fullImgUri);   // http://management.bu.edu/files/2012/01/brazilsal.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the images using the attribute starts with selector `[attr^=value]`, then set it's src value using `$.fn.attr`.

```
$('img[src^="/files"]').attr(function(i,src){
  return "http://management.bu.edu" + src;
});
```